# How far away are the two components of the Rigel system?

Tags: star, rigel, system

How far away is Rigel A and B and what is the angular diameter of Rigel B from A?

Answer (score 1):

Rigel is about 250-300 parsecs distant (800-1000) light years) and Rigel B (and C) are 9.5 arcseconds separate from Rigel.  This would correspond to a distance of over 2200 AU.

There are a number of uncertainties.  The distance of Rigel isn't know well (it is too bright for the Gaia space telescope), and the orbit of B around A isn't known well, but it is unlikely that we are looking at the system perfectly straight on.